# index.dat automatic removal

Tags: windows

How do I remove index.dat files automatically in Windows XP?
Is it possible to do it every time system starts?

I have tried CCleaner and Index.dat Suite with no success, CCleaner won't find the index.dat files, Index.dat Suite won't delete them because "they are in use".

Answer (score 1):

I have found this link might be useful for you
[Delete Remove Index.dat Files](http://www.compu-docs.com/indexdat.htm)

It refers to a method for auto-deletion upon shutdown for Win 2K/ XP Pro